# Tikz to draw timeline progress of an infection

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hello, am asking if someone could help me draw this timeline diagram. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

Here it is:

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\node[align=center] at (1,0.5) {Susceptible\\stage};
\node[align=center] at (2.25,1.85) {Time of\\infection};
\draw [thick,->] (2.25,1.4) -- (2.25,0.15);
\node[align=center] at (3.15,0.85) {Latent\\period};
\draw [thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,raise=0pt}] (2.5,0.15) -- (3.75,0.15);
\draw [thick,->] (4,0.85) -- (4,0.15);
\node[align=center] at (6.25,0.6) {Infectious period};
\draw [thick,->] (8.25,0.85) -- (8.25,0.15);
\node[align=center] at (9.15,0.5) {Immune\\stage};
\draw [thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,raise=0pt}] (4.25,0.15) -- (8,0.15);
\draw [thick,->] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\draw [thick,->] (4.6,-0.85) -- (4.6,-0.15);
\draw [thick,->] (7.65,-0.4) -- (7.65,-0.15);
\draw [thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,raise=0pt,mirror}] (4.75,-0.15) -- (7.5,-0.15);
\node[align=center] at (6.25,-0.85) {Symptomatic\\period};
\node[align=center] at (4.6,-1.3) {Onset of\\symptoms};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

With some preparation of drawing elements, you can wrote relativelly compact code for time line:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style = {align=center},
          Line/.style = {-angle 90, shorten >=2pt},
    Brace/.style args = {#1}{semithick, decorate, decoration={brace,#1,raise=2pt,
                             pre=moveto,pre length=2pt,post=moveto,post length=2pt,}},
            ys/.style = {yshift=#1}
                    ]
\linespread{0.8}                    
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate[right=22mm of a]    (b);
\coordinate[right=16mm of b]    (c);
\coordinate[right= 5mm of c]    (d);
\coordinate[right=24mm of d]    (e);
\coordinate[right= 5mm of e]    (f);
\coordinate[right=22mm of f]    (g);

\draw[Line] (a) -- node[above] {Susceptible\\stage}    (b) -- (f)
                -- node[above] {Immune\\stage}         (g) node[below left] {time};
\draw[Brace] (b) -- node[above=3pt] {Latent\\period}(c);
\draw[Brace] (c) -- node[above=3pt] {Infectious period} (f);
\draw[Brace=mirror] (d) -- node[below=3pt] {Symptomatic\\period} (e);
\draw[Line] ([ys=11mm] b) node[above] {Time of\\infection} -- (b);
\draw[Line] ([ys=7mm]  c) -- (c);
\draw[Line] ([ys=7mm]  f) -- (f);
\draw[Line] ([ys=-11mm] d) node[below] {Onset of\\symptoms} -- (d);
\draw[Line] ([ys=-7mm]  e) -- (e);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

If you not like to determine coordinates of time lines, you can instead `(a)` use `(0,0)` etc.